# How to add an attribute to a TerminalNode

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm working on an antlr grammar which has a rule like `operation : REGISTER '=' OPERATION TYPE OPERATOR ',' OPERATOR`. The type is defined in this way `TYPE : 'int' NUMBER '*'?`. 
Now I have created a basic visitor that overrides `visitOperation` and all works fine.

At this point I would like to have the ability to identify if a type was a pointer or not depending by the presence of the *. I tried using `locals`, `@parser` and `@lexer` but none of them allows me to do something `ctx->TYPE()->isPointer()`. I noticed that `TYPE` is a `TerminalNode` so it might not be possible.

What do you recommend then? Just create a local HashMap and store there some sort of identifier?

EDIT:

I simplified the grammar in order to better describe my use case. I would like to able to parse instructions like:

```
r4 = add int32* a,b
r5 = add int8 c,d
```

The grammar I'm using is:

```
grammar G;      

prog:   (expr NEWLINE)+;

expr    : operation
    ;

operation   : REGISTER '=' 'add' TYPE WORD ',' WORD
        ;

REGISTER    :   'r' NUMBER
        ;

TYPE        : 'int' NUMBER '*'?
        ;

WORD        :   (LETTER)+
        ;

NEWLINE  : [\r\n]+ ;
WS: [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
INT      : [0-9] ;

LETTER   : [a-z] ;

NUMBER  : (INT)+
    ;
```

All seems to be working fine:

```
grun G expr -tokens main.txt
[@0,0:1='r4',<REGISTER>,1:0]
[@1,3:3='=',<'='>,1:3]
[@2,5:7='add',<'add'>,1:5]
[@3,9:14='int32*',<TYPE>,1:9]
[@4,16:16='a',<WORD>,1:16]
[@5,17:17=',',<','>,1:17]
[@6,18:18='b',<WORD>,1:18]
[@7,19:19='\n',<NEWLINE>,1:19]
[@8,20:21='r5',<REGISTER>,2:0]
[@9,23:23='=',<'='>,2:3]
[@10,25:27='add',<'add'>,2:5]
[@11,29:33='int8*',<TYPE>,2:9]
[@12,35:35='c',<WORD>,2:15]
[@13,36:36=',',<','>,2:16]
[@14,37:37='d',<WORD>,2:17]
[@15,38:38='\n',<NEWLINE>,2:18]
[@16,39:38='<EOF>',<EOF>,3:0]
```

Unfortunately now I don't know how to have something `ctx->TYPE()->isAPointer()`.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but transforming type as you suggested I wouldn't be able to use it in my operation rule anymore. Maybe an example would be useful when you have time. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I just edited my question. I hope you have enough context now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do something like this:

```
operation
 : REGISTER '=' 'add' type WORD ',' WORD
 ;

type
 : TYPE STAR?
 ;

TYPE
 : 'int' NUMBER
 ;

STAR
 : '*'
 ;
```

Inside your `visitOperation()`, you can then do:

```
boolean isAPointer = ctx.type().STAR() != null;
```